# Setting Detail Text label from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uitableview, uidatepicker

I haven't had as much trouble in `xcode` until I started building a `tableView`. All of this is being done in code, I don't like using **interface builder**. There is a string `@"Date"` to hold its place. The table is mutable and new cells are added every time you select the add button on **navigation bar**. I am having trouble setting the `detailTextLabel` in the selected cell. I created a `UIDatePicker` to select a date and save it to the `deatailTextLabel` in the selected cell. I have a button on each cell that brings up a `UIDatePicker` and everything closes as it should. But I don't know how to set the `detailTextLabel` to the date selected when the `UIDatePicker` closes.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *aTableIdentifier = @"aTableIdentifier";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: aTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                reuseIdentifier:aTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];


    cell.textLabel.text = [workoutName objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Date";

    self.setDate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    self.setDate.frame = CGRectMake(268, 10.0, 44.0, 44.0);
    [self.setDate setTitle:@"Date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.setDate setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [cell addSubview:self.setDate];
    [self.setDate addTarget:self action:@selector(showDatePicker) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

-(void)showDatePicker{


    self.myDatePicker = [UIDatePicker new];
    self.myDatePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0,275, 320, 210);
    self.myDatePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    [self.view addSubview:self.myDatePicker];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognize = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)];
    tapGestureRecognize.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognize];

}



-(void)dismissDatePicker:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd yyyy"];
    [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.myDatePicker.date];
    dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    dateLabel.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.myDatePicker.date];

    [self.myDatePicker removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

Now I'm not sure if I even set this table up correctly(most likely not) because I when I select a cell it, pushes to another `viewController` but that doesn't show the correct information(Not my question right now).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have a UITableViewCell subclass with a UIButton property on it, or to set up a completionHandler block, or to set the UIDatePickerDelegate to the UITableViewCell subclass, but just working with what you've presented, here's a possible, untested solution:

**NOTE: This assumes you can't add a row to the table while you are in the process of selecting from the date picker. This also assumes you only have 1 section in your table.**

You could set the "tag" property of each "setDate" button to the "row" integer inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath: function, like this:

`self.setDate.tag = row;`

Then change this line:

```
[self.setDate addTarget:self action:@selector(showDatePicker) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

To this:

```
[self.setDate addTarget:self action:@selector(showDatePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Adding the colon to the end of 'showDatePicker' will send the button object along with the method. Then, you have to alter the showDatePicker method to accept the button object like this:

```
-(void)showDatePicker:(id)sender
```

Then use the 'sender' object (which is your setDate button) like this:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
```

You can then get the 'tag' property off the button, which is the row of the table that button corresponds to. Assign it as a tag to 'tapGestureRecognize' like this:

```
tapGestureRecognize.tag = button.tag;
```

Then the method dismissDatePicker's 'gestureRecognizer' object will contain the tag, which corresponds again to the table row the user is editing. Recreate the cell like:

```
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:gestureRecognizer.tag inSection:0];
```

Let's say your UITableView is named 'myTableView'. You can get a reference to the original cell like this:

```
UITableViewCell *theCell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
```

FINALLY, you can alter the cell's detailTextView:

```
theCell.detailTextLabel.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.myDatePicker.date];
```